# jHiccup: histogram data seems inconsistent

Tags: java, performance

I'm running an application with Azul's jHiccup. The application is started via jsvc with -javaagent option. jHiccup settings are default (except for output filename).

The application runs for ~107 minutes. However, if I add up all the values from the resulting `hgrm` file, total length of the hiccups seems too large.

I calculate the sum of the hiccup values like this:

```
Sum( (TotalCountIncludingThisValue[n] - TotalCountIncludingThisValue[n-1]) * Value[n] )
```

The result is 12.75 mln., or ~213 minutes (presuming the values are in milliseconds). That is about twice the duration of the application run.

`Total count * Mean` (from the bottom of the histogram values) also give 12 mln., so the formula is likely to be correct.

For comparison, I added up "Application time" and "Stopped time" from GC log. The results are close to what I expect: ~105 min. app time and ~2 min. stopped time.

---

I've accidentally overwritten the original files, so these are the example files from a different run:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/644287/jHiccup/hiccup.dat
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/644287/jHiccup/hiccup.dat.hgrm

The run took ~79 minutes (17:50-19:09), however Mean*TotalCount is ~23 mln. (that is, 380 minutes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: [Keeping my original mistaken post below]

Ok. So we both had the math wrong (both in your question and in my initial answer). The sanity check that says (Total Count * Mean( should be roughly equal to the runtime is simply bogus math.

This is simply demonstrated with the following thought exercise:

the following very simple scenario: You measure an application that runs perfectly (Idle, all intervals showing 0 hiccup) for 100 seconds. Then you ^Z the system for 100 seconds. Then you let it run in the foreground again and immediately ^C it. Total run time is 200 seconds.

Here are some proper, "how a human would describe this in numbers" statements about such a system:

- The 99.99%'ile will be very close to 100,000 msec.
- The 10%'ile, 20%'ile, ... 50%'ile will all be very close to 0 msec.
- During the 1st 100 seconds (and the first 100,000 sample periods), the mean is 0 msec.
- During the 2nd 100 seconds (and the second 100,000 sample periods) the mean is 50,000 msec.
- The overall mean is 25,000 milliseconds (over the total run time of 200 second period).

But there will (properly) be 200,000 results reported in the TotalCount for the histogram (one for each 1msec of elapsed time).

So (Mean * Total Count) = 200,000 * 25,000 == 5,000,000,000

That's 25,000x as much as the wall clock time. And there is nothing wrong with that. There is an ~N^2 thing going on with that multiplication (actually N * (N-1) / 2), and that's exactly how it would properly behave...

The key here is that for each percentile, the histogram [correctly] reports the percentage of overall random samples (performed without coordination over time) that would encounter hiccup levels below a certain magnitude. When a single long freeze occurs (e.g. as seen in the 2,654 msec max in your sample output), that's not 1 point in time that would be affected. There would be as many sample points in time affected as there are milliseconds in the freeze. Properly measured and represented, a single freeze would generate roughly 1 count per msec, with values varying linearly between the max value and 0 (2654msec, 2653msec, 2652msec, ... 3msec, 2msec, 1msec). This is simply the right way to calculate the spread of the possible latencies that that a random, uncoordinated sample would have encountered.

I'm somewhat embarrassed, because my original answer repeated the same mistaken assumption that I warn about (with graphs in slides that exactly discuss the above scenario) in my talk titled "How NOT to measure Latency" (http://www.infoq.com/presentations/latency-pitfalls , and this is under "The coordinated omission problem" about 32 minutes in). I built both jHiccup and HdrHistogram with the right math to avoid this problem, which is why you see the right results in your data.

In fact, had your sanity check shown "good" numbers, with max times in the 1000s of msec, that would be a good indication that the measurement system is exhibiting coordinated omission...

-- Gil.

-------- Original Answer, which was "wrong" -----------

Can you post an example .hgrm data set that shows this? Files I just looked at seem to show a close relationship between the total instrumented run time and the counts in the .hgrm file. The simplest sanity test is that Total Count * Mean (both reported at the bottom of the file) should be very close to runtime. That data come from the same histogram that produces the percentile lines...

Note that the counts at the percentile lines are not additive for a pretty simple reason. Two percentile levels could be reported for the same exact value. This is quite common for long runs that have fairly little noise in them. However, your math above (only counting the delta counts) "should" work right.

[Small note, your math is off by 1 line: Each percentile line shows the percentile and count of values that have values at or below the value on the line. So value should be multiplied by the delta between counts at the next line (n+1) and the count at "this" line (n), but that should not have made a big difference in you measurement].

Below is a sample file forma control run that took ~1685 seconds, where jHiccup started instrumenting 30 seconds into the run (so ~1655 seconds of instrumented time). Using excel on this data set, the results of:

Sum( (TotalCountIncludingThisValue[n+1] - TotalCountIncludingThisValue[n]) * Value[n] )

Shows about ~16237 seconds, and mean * total count shows ~16591 seconds.

### jHiccup histogram report, Mon Apr 22 15:28:07 CDT 2013 :

Value, Percentile, TotalCountIncludingThisValue

```
1.01 0.000000000000         47
1.06 0.100000000000     483774
1.06 0.200000000000     483774
1.06 0.300000000000     483774
1.10 0.400000000000     628589
1.11 0.500000000000     804685
1.12 0.550000000000    1024190
1.12 0.600000000000    1024190
1.12 0.650000000000    1024190
1.13 0.700000000000    1388741
1.13 0.750000000000    1388741
1.13 0.775000000000    1388741
1.13 0.800000000000    1388741
1.13 0.825000000000    1388741
1.13 0.850000000000    1388741
1.13 0.875000000000    1388741
1.13 0.887500000000    1388741
1.13 0.900000000000    1388741
1.13 0.912500000000    1388741
1.14 0.925000000000    1471124
1.14 0.937500000000    1471124
1.14 0.943750000000    1471124
1.14 0.950000000000    1471124
1.14 0.956250000000    1471124
1.14 0.962500000000    1471124
1.14 0.968750000000    1471124
1.14 0.971875000000    1471124
1.14 0.975000000000    1471124
1.14 0.978125000000    1492169
1.14 0.981250000000    1492169
1.14 0.984375000000    1492169
1.14 0.985937500000    1492169
1.14 0.987500000000    1492169
1.14 0.989062500000    1492169
1.15 0.990625000000    1500639
1.15 0.992187500000    1500639
1.15 0.992968750000    1500639
1.15 0.993750000000    1500639
1.15 0.994531250000    1500639
1.16 0.995312500000    1504895
1.16 0.996093750000    1504895
1.16 0.996484375000    1504895
1.16 0.996875000000    1504895
1.16 0.997265625000    1504895
1.16 0.997656250000    1504895
1.17 0.998046875000    1506535
1.17 0.998242187500    1506535
1.17 0.998437500000    1506535
1.17 0.998632812500    1506535
1.17 0.998828125000    1506535
1.18 0.999023437500    1507442
1.18 0.999121093750    1507442
1.18 0.999218750000    1507442
1.18 0.999316406250    1507442
1.18 0.999414062500    1507442
1.18 0.999511718750    1507836
1.18 0.999560546875    1507836
1.18 0.999609375000    1507836
1.18 0.999658203125    1507836
1.18 0.999707031250    1507836
1.19 0.999755859375    1508028
1.19 0.999780273438    1508028
1.19 0.999804687500    1508028
1.19 0.999829101563    1508028
1.20 0.999853515625    1508106
1.20 0.999877929688    1508106
1.21 0.999890136719    1508145
1.21 0.999902343750    1508145
1.22 0.999914550781    1508163
1.22 0.999926757813    1508174
1.25 0.999938964844    1508186
1.34 0.999945068359    1508195
1.82 0.999951171875    1508204
2.42 0.999957275391    1508213
3.54 0.999963378906    1508222
4.74 0.999969482422    1508231
5.09 0.999972534180    1508236
5.98 0.999975585938    1508241
6.24 0.999978637695    1508245
7.01 0.999981689453    1508251
7.97 0.999984741211    1508254
8.26 0.999986267090    1508257
8.96 0.999987792969    1508259
9.02 0.999989318848    1508261
9.98 0.999990844727    1508265
10.24 0.999992370605    1508266
11.01 0.999993133545    1508268
11.01 0.999993896484    1508268
11.97 0.999994659424    1508269
13.95 0.999995422363    1508271
14.98 0.999996185303    1508272
14.98 0.999996566772    1508272
16.00 0.999996948242    1508273
16.00 0.999997329712    1508273
17.02 0.999997711182    1508274
18.05 0.999998092651    1508275
18.05 0.999998283386    1508275
18.05 0.999998474121    1508275
18.05 0.999998664856    1508275
19.07 0.999998855591    1508276
19.07 0.999999046326    1508276
19.07 0.999999141693    1508276
19.07 0.999999237061    1508276
19.07 0.999999332428    1508276
19.97 0.999999427795    1508277
19.97 1.000000000000    1508277

#[Mean    =         1.10, StdDeviation   =         0.06]
#[Max     =        19.84, Total count    =      1508277]
#[Buckets =           25, SubBuckets     =          256]
```

Comment: Hi Gil. I've added the example files to the post.
"Total Count * Mean" is much greater than runtime in this case.

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense, thanks a lot! I just didn't understand how to interpret the histogram correctly. The website says a histogram shows "observed hiccup durations at varying percentiles", and that doesn't help much.